# CSS spacing not the same jquery show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

I'm trying to make a more and less button. When I click more everything works but the spacing is messed up! And why isn't the more button next to the last work?

HTML:

```
<div id="s" class="popu"><img class="tri" src="img/whtri.png"/>
    <div class="textb"><center style="font-size:15px;">Item Title</center>
        <span style="font-size:13px;">Description this is an item that is very good and i like it very much<span class="eew">tion this is an item that is very good and i like it very much Descr this is an item that is very good and i like it very much Desc this is an item that is very good and i like it very much ption this is an item</span><span class="highl">More...</span>
        </span>
        <br/>
        <div class="wid">

        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.highl{
    color:#6495ED;
    text-decoration:underline
 }
   .textb{
  padding-left: 5px;

 }
```

JQUERY:

```
 $('body').on('click', '.highl', function(){
 $(".eew").show(200);
```

Comment: Can you either post a fiddle, or an example of what it looks like after you click more ?

Comment: Yes because with the provided code it seems to work : http://jsfiddle.net/NFE6Y/

Comment: @web-tiki Did you forget to save your fiddle?

Comment: this is what it looks like when you press the more button

Comment: We need to see the code that is triggered when you click "more".

Comment: @leo yes but I have already edited my comment and it now works

Comment: the spacing is all messed up as you can see

Comment: Now that you've added the script for the "more" click, it is doing exactly what you've told it to do.  Fix the html and it will work correctly.

Comment: @Archer the css is messed up though the first 2 lines are big spaced and the other are not.

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to help you.  If you use the html & css that you have given us it look nothing like the image you posted.

Comment: I think I have managed to reproduce the issue in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/NFE6Y/1/ am I right?

Comment: @web-tiki Yes thats it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `.show(200)` function toggles the `display` property to `block` so the "more" item is displayed on an new line.

You should use this jquery :

```
$('body').on('click', '.highl', function(){
     $(".eew").css("display", "inline");
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NFE6Y/3/)**